# preg_match_all и cURL и QIWI API

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно немного изменить регулярное выражение в коде php.

Данный скрипт идеально работал, но QIWI обновил свой дизайн а там работа по cURL, и вытаскивание объектов по div'ам, названия которых были изменены на другие.
Ссылка на данный скрипт: [Посмотреть скрипт](https://pastebin.com/97f7FQEh)

Вот кусок кода, который нужно заменить:

```
if (preg_match_all ('|<div class="DateWithTransaction">.*<span class="date">(.*)</span>.*<span class="time">(.*)</span>.*<div class="transaction">(.*)</div>.*</div>|Usi', $cont, $dateWithTransaction) &&
    preg_match_all ('|<div class="IncomeWithExpend (.*)">.*<div class="cash">(.*)</div>|Usi', $cont, $incomeWithExpend) &&
    preg_match_all ('|<div class="ProvWithComment">.*<div class="provider">.*<span class="opNumber">(.*)</span>.*</div>.*<div class="comment">(.*)</div>|Usi', $cont, $provWithComment))
{
    // тут какой-то код
}
```

Была такая верстка:

```
<div class="IncomeWithExpend income"><div class="cash">72,89руб.</div><div class="commission"></div></div>
```

То на что нужно заменить:

```
<div class="history-block-item-header-sum"><div class="history-block-item-header-sum-text"><span class="history-block-item-header-sum-amount income">72,89</span></div></div>
```

Comment: Одно не понятно, зачем парсить сайт киви, если у них есть API ...

Comment: @Топ 5 Обзор может лучше на фриланс?

Answer (score 0):

Замените это регулярное выражение:

```
|<div class="IncomeWithExpend (.*)">.*<div class="cash">(.*)</div>|Usi
```

На это:

```
|<div class="history-block-item-header-sum">.*<span class="history-block-item-header-sum-amount (.*)">(.*)</span>|Usi
```

[Посмотреть работу регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/qHzIru/1)